# Bibdesk 1.7.3 update - new references showing as question marks

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, bibdesk

I had an update to Bibdesk 1.7.3, I've since tried to add citations to my report but they show as question marks. References in my Bibtex file from before the update work perfectly fine. I always use the run sequence PDFLatex > Bibtex > PDFLatex > PDFLatex, I've tried different cite keys and removing references before finding different references for the same source and nothing seems to be working! My code is as follows-

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 10pt]{article}
...
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
...
A now widely accepted theory of the Universe's inception used the idea of inflation and was presented by Alan Guth in 1981 \cite{liddle2015cosmo, guth1981inflate, Ian2002Lawrie}
...
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{LitRevRefs.bib}
\end{document}
```

Ian2002Lawrie is the problem reference. I hope someone can help!

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `.blg` file (that is the log file of the BibTeX run). If it worked before this is unlikely to be the problem, but you should still change `\bibliography{LitRevRefs.bib}` to `\bibliography{LitRevRefs}`. `\bibliography` takes the file name *without* file extension. (On some systems this will cause an error.)

Comment: And what are some of the entries in the bib file that are giving you a problem?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, although I'm unsure of the exact details, it seemed that appending to my Bibdesk file didn't append to my .bbl file. This gave me a 'Ian2002Lawrie not found in database' warning in my .blg file. I'm guessing that this had something to do with the update to 1.7.3, but to resolve the problem I just copied and pasted all of my references into a new file. I also changed the \bibliography file name accordingly, and the situation was resolved.

Comment: Note that adding something to the `.bib` file (which is what BibDesk edits) will never automatically add the respective entry to the `.bbl` file. You always need to make sure the entry will be picked up by BIbTeX (with `\cite` or `\nocite` in your document) and run BibTeX on your document afterwards.